# How can I make a Java app that connects to a MongoDB Atlas Cluster?

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to make a Java app that connects to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. I'm currently using Eclipse as my IDE.

From what I've read I'm supposed to use a Maven project to install dependencies, but since I prefer downloading JAR files and using them in my project I've downloaded 3 files (which are the ones that Maven downloads when you add the dependency for MongoDB): **mongodb-driver-sync-4.1.1**; **mongodb-drive-core-4.1.1** and **bson-4.1.1** from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/ and then added those files to my Java project. Using this method things like MongoDatabase and MongoClient work fine, but the problem is that whenever I try to use `MongoCollection <Document> name = database.getCollection("collection")` I get the error "Document cannot be resolved to a type", as if the IDE wouldn't recognize it. It's also worth noting that when trying to use MongoClientURI I get the same error.

[image]

I've tried creating a Maven project with the dependency mentioned before and it works just fine, I don't get errors from Document nor MongoClientURI, but when I create a class in the "main" folder that Maven creates and try to execute it I get a message error saying "launch error editor does not contain a main type", which of course, the class contains.

[image]

If I try to move the class to src/main/java (which by the way it's where it's first created) I get the same error as when using the Java project

[image]

(Note that MongoDB is the Java project and Mongo is the Maven project)

Guess I'm doing something wrong, so I guess I'll stick with a Java project (also given the fact that I want to use Window Builder and I can't seem to make it work with Maven).

I know it's a lot, but could you guys point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently I wasn't importing `org.bson.*` , which contains the Document class... So that's solved